# java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\SOAPUIdata.xls (The system cannot find the file specified)

Tags: groovy, soapui

Though I have a file with same name and extension in the specified path getting this error. Following is my code:

```
import java.io.*
import jxl.*

def f = new File("D:\\SOAPUIdata.xls")
def wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(f)
def ws = wb.getSheet("Sheet1")
def r = ws.getRows()

for (def i=1;i<r;i++)
{
    Cell c1 = ws.getCell(2,i)
    if (c1.getContents().equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
    {
        Cell c2 = ws.getCell(3,i)
        testRunner.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue("test data",c2.getContents())
        Cell c3 = ws.getCell(1,i)
        testRunner.runTestStepByName(c3.getContents())

    }

}
```

This is the code that I am trying to run in SOAP UI. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Could this be permissions related? Regardless, not enough information in the question to help here. If the file is there and accessible then it should be ok otherwise there is more to the problem then you are asking for.

Comment: what is this statement printing: ***f.canRead()*** ??

Comment: Okay. Let me be more detailed here. I have my SOAP UI free version installed on my D drive. And I have imported one sample "http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx?WSDL" from internet in SOAP UI and saced the same project on D drive again. Now I arranged a smoke test suite and created a separate data sheet in excel format and saved it as SOAPUIdata. Now wrote a grrovy test test for reading a data from the created excel sheet but at running I got this error.

Comment: Mon Mar 20 17:09:11 IST 2017:ERROR:java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\SOAPUIdata.xls (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: May be you want to put in a different directory and give a try?

Comment: I tried that too but still same error.

Comment: This program is just to read values from excel and set the property values in the SOAP UI. So no need to write any printing statement.

Comment: I got the solution..It was not able to identify the sheet because of the excel is not in 97-2003 format.